# Questions on a proof in do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry - Computations with Lie groups and Lie algebras

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry, lie-algebras

I am a little confused with making computations with Lie groups and Lie algebras, and would appreciate very much any help with the following questions.

In page 44 of my Brazilian edition of do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry, he states that if a Lie group $G$ has a bi-invariant metric, the inner product that the metric induces on the Lie algebra $\mathcal G$ satisfies
$$
\langle [U, X], V \rangle = - \langle U, [V, X] \rangle.
$$

He argues in the following way:

For every $a \in G$, the automorphism $R_{a^{-1}}L_a: G \longrightarrow G$ is a diffeomorphism that leaves $e$ fixed.  Therefore, the differential $d(R_{a^{-1}}L_a) = Ad(a): \mathcal G \longrightarrow \mathcal G$ is a linear map.

> First question: the differential above is at $e$, right?

He proceeds:
Explicitly, 
$$
Ad(a)Y = dR_{a^{-1}} dL_a Y = dR_{a^{-1}}Y \quad \forall Y \in \mathcal G
$$

> Second question: Here, the differential $dR_{a^{-1}}$ is computed at $a$, right? So it should be
>   $$
> d(R_{a^{-1}})_a (dL_a)_e Y(e) = d(R_{a^{-1}})_aY(a).
> $$

He now argues that if $x_t$ is the flow of $X \in \mathcal G$ then 
$$
[Y, X] = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac1t (dx_t(Y) - Y).
$$

> Third question: Shouldn't it be $$
> [Y, X] = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac1t (dx_t(Y) - Y)x_t ?
> $$

Following, he claims that since $X$ is left-invariant, then $L_y \circ x_t = x_t \circ L_y$

> Why does it hold?

He then concludes the proof, but the remaining of it I think I can understand

Thanks in advance and kind regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question:** Yes, when dealing with Lie groups, if the base point of a differential is omitted you can assume that it is the identity.

**Second question:** This is a corollary of the first question: $${\rm d}(R_{a^{-1}}\circ L_a)_e(Y(e)) = {\rm d}(R_{a^{-1}})_a{\rm d}(L_a)_e(Y(e)) = {\rm d}(R_{a^{-1}})_a(Y(a)) \in \mathfrak{g}.$$

**Third question:** given two left-invariant fields $X$ and $Y$, $[Y,X] = -[X,Y]$ will be a left invariant field. If you regard $X$ and $Y$ as elements of $\mathfrak{g}$, then $[X,Y]$ will also be an element of $\mathfrak{g}$. A usual abuse of notation is, for $g \in G$ and $v \in T_aG$, to write $gv$ for ${\rm d}(L_g)_a(v)$ and $va$ for ${\rm d}(R_g)_a(v)$. The bracket $[X,Y]$ is supposed to be the Lie derivative $\mathcal{L}_XY$ of $Y$ in the direction of $X$, so you want to mimic the definition $$\lim_{t \to 0}\frac{Y(a+tX(a)) - Y(a)}{t},$$but you cannot subtract $Y(a+tX(a))$ and $Y(a)$ as they lie in different tangent spaces. The workaround is to drag $Y$ using the flow of $X$, so one gets $$[X,Y] = \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{ {\rm d}(x_{-t})_{x_t(a)}Y(x_t(a)) -   Y(a)}{t}.$$Carry all the base points carefully and compare what you get with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_bracket_of_vector_fields#:%7E:text=Conceptually%2C%20the%20Lie%20bracket%20%5BX,the%20flow%20generated%20by%20), for instance.

**Last question:** the flows of left invariant fields consist of right translations, and vice-versa. And left translations commute with right translations in general. For instance, if $X$ is left-invariant, you may check that $x_t(a) = a x_t(e)$ (and $x_t(e)$ earns the better name and notation $\exp(tX)$ or ${\rm e}^{tX}$ -- note that I use different fonts, $e$ for the unit element and ${\rm e}$ for the exponential).

Comment: Thank you very much, but I am having trouble with the answers to the third question.  First, if $a$ is an element of the Lie group and $X(a)$ is an element of the tangent space at $a$, what does $a + tX(a)$ mean? It should be an element of the Lie group so that we can apply $Y$, but I fail to see why this is the case. Also, I do not understand how to get to the expression in the third math line. I woud be the most thankful if you could develop a little bit on these points

Comment: That's precisely the point, $Y(a+tX(a))$ only makes sense in $\Bbb R^n$, but you want a definition of derivative that works on a manifold too, so you replace that by a flow and get a Lie derivative. The expression on the third line is meant to be a definition (it's either that or $[X,Y]f = XYf-YXf$, but they coincide).

Comment: Then why does Manfredo write (see page 30)$[X, Y](p) = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac1t [Y - d\varphi_tY](\varphi_t(p))$, where $\varphi$ is what we are calling $x$? Isn't it wrong, then?

Comment: Oh, maybe he is carrying $p$ to $p + tX$, while you did the other way?

Comment: It's possible that I switched it, I wrote that pretty fast on the other day, but for what is it worth, some books (e.g. McDuff & Salamon) switch the convention for the Lie bracket, so in any case *someone* would say I'm right :P

Comment: I checked Lee's and it is exactly what you wrote

Comment: Regarding the claim that $x_t(a) = ax_t(e)$, how to show this? Probably very simple but I am not seeing it

Comment: In general, $x_t(ab)=ax_t(b)$ if $X$ is left invariant, just check that both sides satisfy the same differential equation with same initial condition (i.e., use the definition of flow).

Comment: Still not able to see it :( I am really confused. That they satisfy the same initial conditions, OK, but I am failing the part regarding the differential equation

Comment: Both sides at $t=0$ yield $ab$. For the left side, the derivative is $X_{x_t(ab)}$. For the right side, the derivative is $aX_{x_t(b)} = X_{ax_t(b)}$, where in the last equal sign we use that $X$ is left invariant and I use the "abuse" of notation mentioned in the answer to the third question.

Comment: Namely, both are the solutions to the problem $\gamma'(t)=X_{\gamma(t)}$ with $\gamma(0)=ab$.

Comment: So when we take the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} ax(t, b)$ the $a$ "moves out" as $(dL_a)_b$? This is my trouble

Comment: Again, $aX_{x_t(b)}$ is a shorthand for ${\rm d}(L_a)_{x_t(b)}(X_{x_t(b)})$.

Comment: Because $(d/dt) L_a(x_t(b))$ is precisely what's in the above comment, due to the chain rule.

Comment: "Chain  Rule", that's what I needed to hear. Crystal clear now. Thanks very much for the patience :D